# SQL Server error using the CONCAT function in a pivot aggregated function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query which outputs a pivot.

What I am trying to do is add a `CONCAT` function to the `pivot` but I am getting the following error:

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized aggregate function.

My current code (Which gives the error):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0) Time,  AREA, COUNT(BLOB) BLOBs, CARS
FROM 
(SELECT BLOB, Time, CARS, DRIVER, [MK], AREA, Tier FROM (
SELECT [BLOB Nbr] BLOB, Time, CARS, [From PT], [To PT], [From PN], [To PN], DRIVER, [MK],
CASE AREA
WHEN '01' THEN '02' WHEN '03' THEN '02'
WHEN '05' THEN '06' WHEN '07' THEN '06'
WHEN '09' THEN '10' WHEN '11' THEN '10'
ELSE AREA END AREA, 
Position, Tier
FROM (
SELECT [BLOB Nbr], T_IME Time, [C NAME] CARS, [From PT], [To PT], [From PN], [To PN], [C V] DRIVER, [MK],
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN LEFT(RIGHT([From PN],6),2) ELSE LEFT(RIGHT([To PN],6),2) END AREA,
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN LEFT(RIGHT([From PN],4),2) ELSE LEFT(RIGHT([To PN],4),2) END Position,
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN RIGHT([From PN],2) ELSE RIGHT([To PN],2) END Tier
FROM mytable c
WHERE ([From PT] = 'DRIVER' OR [To PT] = 'DRIVER')
) a ) b ) c
GROUP BY dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0),  AREA, CARS) src pivot(CONCAT(sum(BLOBs),CARs) for AREA in ([02],[06],[10])) piv;
```

If I change my second line to (Removing `CARs`):

```
SELECT dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0) Time,  AREA, COUNT(BLOB) BLOBs
```

And if I change my `GROUP BY` to (Removing `CARs` and the `CONCAT` function):

```
GROUP BY dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0),  AREA) src pivot(sum(BLOBs) for AREA in ([02],[06],[10])) piv;
```

It works but I want the concatenation in the results.

Current working output:

```
Time                      02    06      10
2018-05-07 16:00:00.000   11    NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000   2     7       NULL
2018-05-07 16:30:00.000   NULL  8       NULL
2018-05-07 16:45:00.000   9     NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000   9     NULL    8
```

Expected output (With `CONCAT`):

```
Time                      02        06      10
2018-05-07 16:00:00.000   BMW11     NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000   BMW2      KIA7    NULL
2018-05-07 16:30:00.000   NULL      KIA8    NULL
2018-05-07 16:45:00.000   BMW9      NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000   BMW9      NULL    FIAT8
```

Sample Data from the query, without the `PIVOT`:

```
Time                        AREA    BLOBs   CARs
2018-05-07 16:00:00.000     02      11      BMW
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000     02      2       BMW
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000     06      7       KIA
2018-05-07 16:30:00.000     06      8       KIA
2018-05-07 16:45:00.000     02      9       BMW
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000     02      9       BMW
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000     10      8       FIAT
```

Raw Sample Data from table:

Comment: This would likely be far easier to answer with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Adding now :) ...

Comment: What about the sample data? That's just the expected output and current output.

Comment: @Larnu Added output without the pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE #PIVOT (Time  DATETIME, AREA INT, BLOBs INT, CARs VARChar (10))

insert into #PIVOT values 
 ('2018-05-07 16:00:00.000', 02, 11     ,'BMW')
,('2018-05-07 16:15:00.000', 02, 2      ,'BMW')
,('2018-05-07 16:15:00.000', 06, 7      ,'KIA')
,('2018-05-07 16:30:00.000', 06, 8      ,'KIA')
,('2018-05-07 16:45:00.000', 02, 9      ,'BMW')
,('2018-05-07 17:00:00.000', 02, 9      ,'BMW')
,('2018-05-07 17:00:00.000', 10, 8      ,'FIA')


select
 Time, CARs + convert (varchar (10), [02]) [02]
 , CARs + convert (varchar (10), [06]) [06], CARs + convert (varchar (10), [10]) [10]
from (
 select
 *
 from #PIVOT
) p
pivot
(
max (BLOBs) for area in ([02],[06], [10])
) t

Time                        02      06      10
2018-05-07 16:00:00.000     BMW11   NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000     BMW2    NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 16:45:00.000     BMW9    NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000     BMW9    NULL    NULL
2018-05-07 17:00:00.000     NULL    NULL    FIA8
2018-05-07 16:15:00.000     NULL    KIA7    NULL
2018-05-07 16:30:00.000     NULL    KIA8    NULL
```

Let me work for dynamic query.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can try  below - you need to use an aggregate function in pivot so in your case you can use `max(CONCAT(sum(BLOBs),CARs))`

```
    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0) Time,  AREA, COUNT(BLOB) BLOBs, CARS
FROM 
(SELECT BLOB, Time, CARS, DRIVER, [MK], AREA, Tier FROM (
SELECT [BLOB Nbr] BLOB, Time, CARS, [From PT], [To PT], [From PN], [To PN], DRIVER, [MK],
CASE AREA
WHEN '01' THEN '02' WHEN '03' THEN '02'
WHEN '05' THEN '06' WHEN '07' THEN '06'
WHEN '09' THEN '10' WHEN '11' THEN '10'
ELSE AREA END AREA, 
Position, Tier
FROM (
SELECT [BLOB Nbr], T_IME Time, [C NAME] CARS, [From PT], [To PT], [From PN], [To PN], [C V] DRIVER, [MK],
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN LEFT(RIGHT([From PN],6),2) ELSE LEFT(RIGHT([To PN],6),2) END AREA,
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN LEFT(RIGHT([From PN],4),2) ELSE LEFT(RIGHT([To PN],4),2) END Position,
CASE WHEN [From PT] = 'DRIVER' THEN RIGHT([From PN],2) ELSE RIGHT([To PN],2) END Tier
FROM mytable c
WHERE ([From PT] = 'DRIVER' OR [To PT] = 'DRIVER')
) a ) b ) c
GROUP BY dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,Time)/15)*15,0),  AREA, CARS) src pivot(max(CONCAT(sum(BLOBs),CARs)) for AREA in ([02],[06],[10])) piv;
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Incorrect syntax near '('.` error on the GROUP BY line

Comment: @Matt, it would be great if you create a db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ here then it would be easy to find the error for me

Comment: @fa86 I have added some sample data to the question